# Can we write one Graph to aggregate Gradient and value in CPU

Tags: tensorflow

[Tensorflow distributed training] Can we write one Graph with APIs to share variables from ps at CPU end, and all GPUs pull latest values from CPU instead of PS. In addition, all GPU push gradient to cpu end instead of pservers, then indirectly push merged gradients to pservers.

Answer (score 0):

You can place any op you want on any device you want with judicious applications of `with tf.device("device_name"):` blocks. So yes, it's possible to do this kind of aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. 

Even though I do not know how to do it right now, I have confidence with it to get better distributed performance.
With naive idea, I can place all variables allocated on ps, and all workers share variables from ps and have duplicated Variables in CPU host memory. However, how to enable all GPUs get variables from local HOSTs instead of ps?

Comment: You can do "with ops.device("/job:worker/cpu:0"):  cpu_cached_variable = tf.identity(variable_on_ps) and then use cpu_cached_variable in your GPU code"

Comment: thanks for your kind rely, I will try it within several days, and give your response, even with distributed performance.
If you have some more suggestions for running distributed training with Mulit-nodes which owns server GPUs as well for each node, I will be grateful.